# Spring Integration Queue Error Handling

Tags: spring-integration

I have a Spring Integration DSL flow which pulls in data from a rest API, transforms it and sends it through to a different rest API.

After data is fetched, it sends a message into a queue channel which does the rest of the processing. While the queue is working the original thread goes and fetches more data.

The issue that I am having is that any errors thrown from the queue are not processed until it has finished processing all the data, but I want it to stop the processing and throw the error right away because the whole process can take a long time but I want it to stop on the first error found.

Gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel = "syncErrorChannel")
@Service
public interface CrmGateway {
  @Gateway(requestChannel = "departmentSyncInput", replyChannel = "departmentSyncOutput")
  @Payload("new String()")
  Object syncDepartments();
}
```

Flow:

```
/**
   * Fetches data from the source api and passes it on to the split channel to process it If the
   * response indicates it has more data to fetch then it is also loaded
   *
   * @return {@link IntegrationFlow}
   */
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow sync() {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from("departmentSyncInput")
      .handle(this::fetchDomain)
      .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h.put("nextLink", "payload.getNext()")))
      .routeToRecipients(r -> r
        .recipient("departmentSplitChannel")
        .recipient(
          "departmentSyncInput",
          p -> p.getPayload() instanceof Wrapper
            && ((Wrapper) p.getPayload()).getNext() != null
        ))
      .get();
  }

  /**
   * Split data from the api into individual models and send them to the target service
   *
   * @return {@link IntegrationFlow}
   */
  @Bean
  IntegrationFlow split() {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from("departmentSplitChannel")
      .transform(Wrapper.class, Wrapper::getContent)
      .split()
      .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100)))
      .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("errorChannel", "syncErrorChannel"))
      .handle((payload, headers) -> log("Syncing", payload, payload))
      .transform(Department.class, transformer)
      // exception happens here
      .handle(DepartmentDTO.class, (payload, headers) -> service.upsertDepartment(payload))
      .handle((payload, headers) -> log("Synced", payload, payload))
      .aggregate()
      .get();
  }
```

Error handler:

```
@Bean
  IntegrationFlow errorHandler() {
    return IntegrationFlows
      .from("syncErrorChannel")
      .handle(Exception.class, (payload, headers) -> {
        payload.printStackTrace();
        return payload;
      })
      .get();
  }
```

I also tried using `IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")` with the same results.

I have tried using a `Future` too and it behaves the same so that when I call `get()` I get the error, but this is still happening at the end.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `queue` channel definition in your flow, but I guess you mean that `.channel(c -> c.executor())`. Would be better if you share logs on the matter as well.

What I can say that you try to override `errorChannel` header which is `TemporaryReplyChannel` in case of Gateway.

So, the error is send to the gateway's process and crashes it in case of `split`.

I suggest you to try with the `h.header("errorChannel", "syncErrorChannel", true)` to really override that header.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done it. Is using `c -> c.executor()` different to a queue? This is DSL that I had converted from XML but I haven't used SI DSL before.

Comment: Well, from big height it is really queue, because you feed a task for executor which store them in the internal queue if there is no free threads to handle it . What am I talking about is QueueChannel for polling-specific behavior